# How to programmatically grant permissions between SQL Server databases

Tags: sql-server, database, permissions

I have recently developed an application that stores data in a database I control that I want to be accessed by a component of an ERP, Dynamics GP (A Navigation list). Both databases are inside the same instance and I have full administrative control of the entire environment.

My issue is that this GP component executes the SQL (select statements) under the account that is currently logged into the ERP.

I am able to manually grant permissions to individual user accounts, but I am looking to find a way to grant this for all possible future users.
As a function of the ERP, all new users are added into a database role of one of its own databases (named DYNGRP), but I do not appear to be able to assign permissions to this on a database level.

I have attempted to research this but haven't found any obvious answers. One approach I was considering was trying to write a DDL trigger to fire whenever a user was added to this DYNGRP, to also create a user with permissions in my secondary database.

If I am trying to solve this problem the wrong way would someone be able to point me in the right direction?

Comment: An approach using [application roles](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187550.aspx) might work here.

Comment: Is the SQL being executed in the "foreign" database ad hoc or a stored procedure?

Comment: Unfortunately the ERP only allows for direct select statements, and will not let me execute a stored proc.  At the moment I believe it may be possible to setup a view on my main ERP database and use table security to grant permissions to this view, though I am unsure of if this is possible at this stage.